# Package release date in Debian

Tags: debian, dpkg

How do I find the release date of the current package version? I don't see it listed in package info:

```
$ dpkg -p libmagic1
Package: libmagic1
Priority: standard
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 2445
Maintainer: Daniel Baumann <daniel.baumann@progress-technologies.net>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: file
Version: 5.11-2+deb7u9
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
Suggests: file
Size: 204520
Description: File type determination library using "magic" numbers
 This library can be used to classify files according to magic number tests. It
 implements the core functionality of the file command.
Homepage: http://www.darwinsys.com/file/
```

Answer (score 2):

The top of the installed changelog will tell you when the installed version of the package was released:

```
$ zcat /usr/share/doc/libmagic1/changelog.Debian.gz | head
file (1:5.35-4+deb10u1) buster-security; urgency=high

  * Cherry-pick commit to restrict the number of CDF_VECTOR elements.
    Closes: #942830 [CVE-2019-18218]

 -- Christoph Biedl <debian.axhn@manchmal.in-ulm.de>  Tue, 22 Oct 2019 21:57:17 +0200

file (1:5.35-4) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Cherry-pick fix for JSON detection. Closes: 922874
```

So the current Debian 10 package was released on October 22, 2019; as was [the Debian 9 package](https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/f/file/changelog-15.30-1deb9u3):

```
file (1:5.30-1+deb9u3) stretch-security; urgency=high

  * Cherry-pick commit to restrict the number of CDF_VECTOR elements.
    Closes: #942830 [CVE-2019-18218]

 -- Christoph Biedl <debian.axhn@manchmal.in-ulm.de>  Tue, 22 Oct 2019 22:20:07 +0200

file (1:5.30-1+deb9u2) stable; urgency=high

  * Avoid reading past the end of buffer. Closes: #901351
```

(I don’t have a Debian 7 system handy to check, but this command will work there too.)

Comment: Thanks. Seems a bit hacky though. Don't they have it stored somewhere in a more "systematic" way in the dpkg database? Is it assured that all those changelogs will have the same format and a note for every release?

Comment: We *require* that “those changelogs” all have the same format and a note for every release.

Comment: "We" meaning? :-)

Comment: The Debian project. I’m a Debian developer.

Comment: OK. So I guess there's no more direct way to get the release date (yet)?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of...